# Arrays and nested Loops

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop

Question in book:

Write a loop that fills an array values with ten random numbers between 1 and 100. Write code for two nested loops that fill values with ten different random numbers between 1 and 100.

My question: Why does this require a nested loop?

My code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class ArrayPractice
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int[] a = new int[10];
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        { 

            a[i] = 1 + random.nextInt(100);

            System.out.print(a[i]+ " ");

    }

}
```

Comment: I think the key word here is "different".

Comment: 10 DIFFERENT random numbers. You need to keep an array of numbers that you've used already, and loop through that everytime you pick a random number. If you've used any of them, then skip and try another random number

Comment: Of course you could still do that without a nested loop, but it probably is the simplest way

Comment: @RichardTingle The only other solutions I can think of in my head are painfully obtuse, and probably not any more efficient at the end of the day

Comment: @Cruncher A hash set doesn't seem that obtuse.

Comment: @pamphlet was assuming standard lib.

Comment: I thought Hashset was standard

Comment: @rgettman, how can I print out 10 different numbers without the occurrence of two numbers coming out the same?

Comment: Don't initialize i ahead of the loop. @RichardTingle: It's obviously part of learning loops, so using other ways is off topic here.

Comment: @RoyKesserwani Simple solution; Keep a list of the used numbers (arraylist?) and check each time if you've used a random number, if you have then re-roll. You could also use annother array for the used numbers and loop through it each time which is what I think the book is getting at

Comment: @RichardTingle: The list of used values is already there; it's the array so far to i-1.

Comment: @userunknown yeah..... In my defence I have a cold, that is exactly what Roy should do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you don't need to import Array just for using arrays.

You can check for existing values rnd in the array so far, and decrement the counter of the outer loop, as soon as you find a value repeated:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class ArrayPractice
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int[] a = new int[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        { 
            int rnd = 1 + random.nextInt (100);
            a[i] = rnd;
            System.out.print (a [i] + " ");
            for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
            {
                if (a[j] == rnd) --i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class ArrayPractice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();
        int[] array = new int[10];
        int index = 0;

        while(index < array.length){
            int number = 1 + random.nextInt(100);

            boolean found = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
                int elm = array[i];
                if (elm == number) {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!found){
                array[index++] = number;
            }
        }
        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(array));
    }
}
```